# PySimpleGui SystemTray.notify Duration Argument

Tags: python, pysimplegui

I want to send a Windows 10 notification using PySimpleGUIs SystemTray.notify class method which has a specific duration or doesnt vanish at all until clicked.

In the docs you can find the following sentence:
"There are options to control the fade, how long things are displayed, the alpha channel, etc.. See the call signature at the end of this document."

But I could not find more infos in the document.

I tried (out of the blue) `sg.SystemTray.notify('Notification Title', 'This is the notification message', duration=10)` which will return `notify() got an unexpected keyword argument 'duration'`

Does someone know how to set the duration etc.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer [SystemTray](https://pysimplegui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/call%20reference/#systemtray)

Following example show the way, right click on icon to show menu.

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

menu_def =  ['My_Menu', ['Notify', 'Show', 'Quit']]
tray = sg.SystemTray(menu=menu_def, data_base64=sg.EMOJI_BASE64_HAPPY_IDEA)

while True:

    event = tray.read()

    if event in (sg.WINDOW_CLOSED, 'Quit'):
        break
    elif event == 'Notify':
        tray.notify("Notify", "You got this notify", fade_in_duration=50, display_duration_in_ms=1000, alpha=0.5)
    elif event == 'Show':
        tray.show_message("Message", "You got this message", time=(50, 1000))

tray.close()
```

Comment: If using tkinter port of PySimpleGUI, you can also use the add-on package psgtray that's pip-installable (https://github.com/PySimpleGUI/psgtray).  You'll get a similar set of capabilities.